# How can I make the abscissa (i.e. the grid line y=0) appear darker or bolder in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridlines

I have a line graph with some points with positive value, and others with negative value (I am plotting odds ratios). I would like to make the y=0 grid line appear darker or bolder so as to make the visuals more apparent. How can I do this with ggplot2?

As an extension of this, I would also like to ask this: is there a way I can make particular grid lines darker or bolder (say, y=5 or a vertical grid line x=-2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding to your ggplot

```
 geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 4) # or whichever size needed
```

For `x`-intercepts, use:

```
geom_vline(xintercept = ...)
```

Comment: Thanks! I repeatedly face a problem with R: I know what I want, and it's usually something simple, but I don't know what term to search with. Once again, thank you :-)

Comment: no problem.  I find that googline "ggplot geom " and a term related to what I want to accomplish helps me find it

Comment: @ChthonicProject, you may also check [these docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/). I think it is basically the help texts for all the `ggplot` functions, but with the output of all examples. It usually doesn't take so much clicking and scrolling before you stumble over something that resembles what you are looking for.